# CNN with text document: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_4: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Tags: python, text, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to add convolutional layer to my CNN model, but I cannot understand the error: **Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_4: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3**.

I have searched on sites for solution, some said I should add an extra dimension, which is quite blurred to my condition.

> I have embedding word dimension of 300, and the max length of each text document is 265. Vocabulary size is 2345.
>   I want to classify the text documents into 3 types.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta , Adam , SGD

# define the model 
embedding_dim = 300

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))

# error occurs here
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(3,300),padding='same',activation='relu'))
```

Any idea on how this error means is a great help! I stuck with this line a half-day.

Comment: If there isn't a specific reason to use CNN, I would suggest using LSTM layer from Keras. If you have to use CNN try Conv1D.

Comment: ok, thank you very much! I try to revise it to Conv1D, Conv1D seems much easier to implement!